# Do I need to repeat the subject+verb a second time in a sentence?

Tags: ellipses, redundancy

Which of the following is correct? Do I need to repeat the "I will"?

> - I will work on that list and send it to you as soon as possible.
> - I will work on that list and I will send it to you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. The first one is usually preferred as having better style.

The grammar issue at work is called [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

We can often leave out one or more words when we can predict or assume what they would be if they were there.

Answer (score 0):

The first one appears to be correct as it doesn't have unneeded redundancy. I've seen some usage like this too:

> I will work on that list and will send to you as soon as possible.